# App Script: How to run a similar script all over the rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following is the "onEdit(e) code which calls other 2 functions. I want to apply the other functions till rows number 11. This script currently works on second row only.

Do I need to copy & paste the similar code and change the row numbers? Or is there any way to do this by scripting?

I'm a complete beginner.

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
 {recordValue()};
 {clear()};
}

/////////

function recordValue() {
  //read the current trigger price in 'Set Alert'!G2 and record it in cell P2
  var triggerPrice = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('G2').getCell(1, 1).getValue();
  var outputCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('P2').getCell(1, 1);
  if (triggerPrice != "") {
  outputCell.setValue(triggerPrice);
}
}

/////////

function clear() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Set Alerts').getRange('S2');
  var rangedata = ss.getCell(1, 1).getValue();
  if (rangedata == "Fired") {
  {var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Set Alerts').getRange('G2').getCell(1, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});};
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to edit these functions is to run a `for` loop, say over the rows 2 to 11:

```
function recordValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts");
  for (var row = 2; row <= 11; row++) {
    var triggerPrice = sheet.getRange('G' + row).getValue();
    if (triggerPrice != "") {
      sheet.getRange('P' + row).setValue(triggerPrice);
    }
  }
}
```

And similarly,

```
function clear() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Set Alerts');
  for (var row = 2; row <= 11; row++) {
    var rangedata = sheet.getRange('S' + row).getValue();
    if (rangedata == "Fired") {
      sheet.getRange('G' + row).clear({contentsOnly: true});
    }
  }
}
```

#### Remarks

- There is no need to call `.getCell(1, 1)` on a one-cell range. There is no separate "cell" class in Apps Script, a cell is just a Range with one cell. All of your calls to getCell were redundant.
- Getting a handle on the sheet first (`var sheet = ...`) shortens subsequent code.
- There is no need to assign the return of `clear` method to anything, if you are not using it (the method returns the range that was cleared).
- As written above, the code still doesn't conform to [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) - namely, it uses multiple getRange / getValue calls to access data, instead of a single `getRange("G2:G11").getValues()`. For such a small number of rows this isn't a major flaw, but something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Hello, what will the code look like if it conform with best practice?